# select ids for which 2 mandatory values are present

Tags: c#, jquery, sql

I've a table -

```
id1 type people
id1 type actor
id2 type people
id3 type people
id2 type politician
id3 type magician
id4 type ps: i love you
id4 type movie
id2 type poet
id3 type singer
```

How can I get all ids which are `people` and `politician`? In our example `id2` should be in final output table. I what thinking of making list over last column over the grouping of column 1 & 2 together as -

```
id1 type {people, actor}
id2 type {people, politician, poet}
id3 type {people, magician, singer}
...
```

and now i can check i column `#3` for `people` and `politician`.

Is there a better way in Sequel with some C# supported methods in queries?

Comment: not to be rude but how come you couldn't do a simple google search on `SQL Tutorial` this question shows extreme lack of effort.. if someone gives you the answer how do you expect to maintain the code if other updates or future enhancements are needed..?

Comment: thanks for concern, i think I made it clear that I'm looking for approach and not direct answers. I also gave my approach first before asking better way. Tell me how can I search this on Google?

Comment: Google and search engines can help people who at least know some thing about it. In my case I don't know what you call this type of normalizing.

Comment: That's what Google searches are for.. to find resources to help you learn.. come on now.. how do you expect to understand or learn SQL if you don't seek out any tutorials..

Comment: thanks for it, I'm seriously thinking about it now.

Comment: [SQL JOINS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) here's a good place to start.. don't Think..just Do..

Comment: There are many different approaches: Self Joins, `INTERSECT`, `GROUP BY/HAVING`, `EXISTS`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in sql using `intersect`.

```
select id from table where type = 'people'
intersect
select id from table where type = 'politician'
```